# Cannot cast to Smart TV from laptop

Tags: firewall, home-networking, streaming, chromecast

I've tried to cast video from my laptop running Windows 8.1 to the Smart TV, and despite the laptop can detect the TV, when trying to send the video stream, on tv I only get to see the video filename and then the screen goes black.

I've tried to cast both from Google Chrome as well as from VLC video player, so I suspect it's some issue with my laptop, Windows Defender/Firewall maybe, but I'm not sure what to check or do, so any help is really appreciated.

VLC in some cases has shown the following message:

> Casting this video requires conversion. This conversion can use all
> the available power and could quickly drain your battery

In VLC logs I get the following message:

> stream_out_chromecast warning: httpd buffer full: dropping 39140B

Thank you

PS: As workaround I've installed VLC in the Smart TV through Android Marketplace, and connected a USB with the video file.